# Unable to Access Elements on MS CRM 365

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, automation, dynamics-crm

Recently I have been tasked with Automating MS CRM 365 with Selenium Automation. I have opted for Using Gradle and Java for this, using IntelliJ.

Currently my issue is when I am on a form page, I am unable to access any elements on that page for data entry or drop-down selection.

I have tried using iFrame switching:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#contentIFrame0")));
```

I have tried selecting from ID, from XPATH & from CSS.

The code is a simple driver.findElement; there isn't anything special about it. I seem to be failing at the most basic part.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("firstname_i")).click();
```

Expected outcome: To be able to access the element and process a Click, followed by either a selection from drop-down or a text entry.

Actual outcome:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #firstname_i
```

[Image to Firefox Inspection of the Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh1o6.png)

I was wondering if there is something in the CSS that's stopping me from accessing the element. I noticed that the element for the 'text' box is under a few layers and is not displayed, unless the top layer is accessed. However I cannot event find that element to follow the flow. Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: Might be useful, https://github.com/Microsoft/EasyRepro

Comment: I could be mistaken since I don't have to switch frames very often in code, but I believe that the parameter when switching is just the frame name itself (in quotes).  It's likely that your frame switch is failing without an error, and subsequently even a corect locator will still not find the element in question.

Comment: @BillHileman From the language bindings I've used, there's typically 3 options for switching into a frame... index, name/id, and passing the actual element. See [this](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @JeffC.

Comment: @BillHileman No problem... not intended to be a "correction" so much as an FYI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of playing about, I noticed that my iframe switch was working however the element I was trying to access was correct just not complete, not sure if this is ever relevant to anyone else but I had to add a method to counter my element issue by select the initial element "name" and then selecting a second element as the input "name_i".

Where as if I tried to select "name_i" initially I get the whole "element not found" as the CSS sets it to invisible unless activated by mouse over/ click on the first element (overlay?).

This seems to be the case across the whole form page.

Never worked with MS 365 before so I have no idea if this is viable or even common.

Thanks.